# Use Shopify Collection Image in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I'm working on a Shopify theme for the first time and am working with Collections. At the moment I have around 8 Collections, of which you can assign a Featured Image to. I was wondering how I can can use the Featured Image URL which is generated like this:

```
<img src="{{ collection.image.src | collection_img_url: '1024x1024' }}" />
```

in my `app.js` file.

I'm using [backstretch.js](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/), so I need that URL to be rendered in my .js file, like so:

```
$(".collection-image .nike").backstretch("nike-collection-image.jpg");
```

Just trying to think of an elegant way to do this. I was thinking of storing the Featured Image URL in a variable, but I'm not sure if that would do the job I want it to do.

Still pretty new to JS, could anyone give me any pointers of how to go about this?

Any help whatsoever is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**Product.liquid**

In `product.liquid` you could store the URL to a property of the window object:

```
<script>
    window.backstretchImage = "{{ collection.image.src | collection_img_url: '1024x1024' }}"
</script>
```

Then use it in your javascript file:

```
$(".collection-image .nike").backstretch(window.backstretchImage);
```

If you are adding more than one item, I would look at a better way of organising it.

**theme.js.liquid**

If you change the extension of your javascript file to `.js.liquid`, any liquid syntax inside will be render, so you could do:

```
$(".collection-image .nike").backstretch({{ collection.image.src | collection_img_url: '1024x1024' }});
```

This would be my choice.

Hope that helps!